# Are mysql_query commands executed in a top->bottom fashion as a .php file is executed?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to build a progress bar loaded for a long running page (yes indexes are obvious solution but currently the dataset/schema prohibits partitioning/proper indexing) so I plan to use a GUID/uniqueID within the query comment to track progess with SHOW_FULL_PROCESSLIST via ajax - but the key to this rests on if the sequential queries are executed in order by php, does anyone know?

Comment: please provide more background to your question; code mostly.

Comment: @jack - see the below polite and helpful answers that required only a working knowledge of mysql/php threading, and I think that you might want to consider changing the -1 if that was you. Thanks for the reply however.

Comment: it just wasn't very obvious (at least to me) from the question why you needed to know this ... it's still sort of vague, but I'm glad you managed to get an answer :) and no, I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @jack no worries - problem is a lot of my code is proprietary under nondisclosure so its really hard to post examples. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL as a database server uses multiple threads to handle multiple running queries. It allocates a thread as and when it received a query from a client i.e. a PHP connection or ODBC connection etc.

However, since you mentioned mysql_query I think there can be 2 things in your mind:

1. if you call mysql_query() multiple times to pass various commands, then MySQL will be passed each query after the previous query is completely executed and the result returned to PHP. So, of course MySQL will seem to then work sequentially although it is actually PHP that is waiting to send MySQL a query till one query is finished.
2. In MySQL5 and PHP5 there is a function called  ([`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)) using which you can pass multiple queries at once to MySQL without PHP waiting for 1 query to end. The function will return all results at once in the same result object. MySQL will actually run all the queries at once using multiple threads and the wait time in this case is substantially less and you also tend to use the server resources available much better as all the queries will run as separate threads.

Comment: +1 - great explanation and very helpful to my case as I have 4-5 queries in my report pages all relating to different datasets/tables. Thanks for the additional info on mysqli_query.

Comment: Great to know it helped you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As Babbage once said, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question." Calls to `mysql_query`, like calls to any other function, execute in the order that they are reached in program flow.

Comment: +1 for the great quote! I am working on my vague questions, as mentioned, a lot of my code is under a nondisclosure, so its very hard to formulate a constructive question that is conducive to getting great answers, but I am getting better. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Order in the file is mostly irrelevant. It's order of execution that matters.

```
<?php

    myCmdFour();
    myCmdTwo();
    myCmdThree();
    myCmdTwo();

    function myCmdTwo() {
        mysql_query(...);
    }

    function myCmdThree() {
        mysql_query(...);
    }

    function myCmdFour() {
        mysql_query(...);
    }

    myCmdFour();
    myCmdThree();
    myCmdTwo();
    myCmdTwo();
?>
```

Although anyone that has PHP files that look like that, needs to seriously rethink things.